# html 5 canvas events

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I want to know if we can select a thing on canvas through our own menu say rectangle and then click on the screen again to get it's coordinates and draw rectangle there? So is this possible by any event or any thing to first select rectangle then wait for a click so that rectangle is draw at that position on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library lets you add events to the drawed things on your canvas [Kinetic](http://www.kineticjs.com/). 
I suggest you take your menu outside of the canvas, it's recommended to use "old elements"(divs) when posible.

Comment: right click any where on page displays a menu we cant take it out of the page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you out. http://forvar.de/js/mcl/examples.interactive.html